# Mysql select if any

Tags: mysql

now I have some queries like

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE row='$row_value'

What should i put in $row_value to show all entries? (I can't delete that part "WHERE row='$row_value'"). Is it possible at all to do what I want?

Comment: basically, by adding `WHERE row='$row_value'` it filters all records where `row='$row_value'`. what do you really want to do?

Comment: you can put `WHERE row=row` (if `row` cannot be Null)

Comment: @ypercube: What about the single quotes (`'$row_value'`)?

Comment: @mellamokb Aye, you are right.

Comment: What kind of system would not allow you to modify your queries?

Comment: Please don't do string interpolation to insert values. [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/) help ensure data is escaped correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try phrasing your where clause like this:

```
where ('$row_value' = 'specialvalue' or (row = '$row_value'))
```

This will allow you to set the value once to return everything or just the results from one comparison.  The special value can be empty:

```
where ('$row_value' = '' or (row = '$row_value'))
```